# Include errors without even having any headers

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, opengl

Hi guys this is my 3rd post in this regard please help.I have 2 files :-arcball.cpp and sample.cpp under source and then arcball.h under header files in a VS 2008 project.Now initial code in sample.cpp was giving me errors so I removed everything and this is the body of sample.cpp :-

```
int main (){

return 0;
}
```

I am surprised it still gives me those same errors.

```
Error   1   error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'glAccum' c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   4   error C2182: 'APIENTRY' : illegal use of type 'void'    c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\gl\gl.h   1152    Viewer
```

Please please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound's to me like you've accidently added some your of .h files to the list of compilation units, instead of just source dependencies.